# What documents to show upon arrival in Doha, Qatar?

Tags: paperwork

I'm a Filipino Citizen and live in Canada. I got a job offer in Qatar and visa approved. What do I need to bring to show immigration in Qatar upon arrival?

Answer (score 2):

For Work Visa, your employer need to send you a visa aproval/entry permit (pdf), which will mention your name and details and work related information on an online print obtained from a government website, in arabic and english. Also, near the travel date, employer need to notify airline (or its partner airline) in Qatar to have no objection of your arrival, also known as "Ok to Board" notification.

Airline will ask you for this permit, and will verify the "Ok To Board", and will let you travel. Once here, you need to show this permit and passport to immigration officer, and a stamp will be put in your passport, with relatively no questions, with a number and note that employer need to start the residence permit process in 7 days or less.

Every employer has a team of the PROs (Public Relation Officer), as soon as you report to work (same day or next day of your arrival), your HR will request your passport and a blood group report from a local clinic. In a week or something you will get Medical Test appointment, and if all ok, in another week it will be fingerprints, and a week after you will get your residence permit card.

Source: Personal experience